# Updating multiple objects inside an array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am facing an issue in updating a collection below is the collection:

```
{
  movieId: 1,
  seats : {
    A : [{isAvailable: true, bookedBy}, {isAvailable: true, bookedBy}, {isAvailable: true, bookedBy}],
    B : [{isAvailable: true, bookedBy}, {isAvailable: true, bookedBy}, {isAvailable: true, bookedBy}],
    C : [{isAvailable: true, bookedBy}, {isAvailable: true, bookedBy}, {isAvailable: true, bookedBy}]
  }
}
```

Now when a user books some seats, I am sending bookedSeats as an array like this:

```
bookedSeats = [{row: "A", col: 0}, {row: "A", col" 1}, {row: "B", col: 2}]
```

here "row" refers to the the key in my "collection.seats" and "col" refers to the corresponding index of the array.

Now I want to update the collections data "isAvailable" to "false",

I tried inserting one more key-value pair in my database collection of each array element called as "seatNo" which stores value as "A0", "A1", "A2".... where "A" is the "row" and "0" is the "col".

Then I tried this query:

```
collection.updateOne( { seats: { $elemMatch: { seatNo: { $eq: bookedTickets[i].row + bookedTickets[i].col }, }, }, }, { $set: { "seats.$.isAvailable": false } } );
```

Schema:

```
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
   name: { type: String, required: true }, 
   timing: { type: String, required: true }, 
   duration: { type: String, required: true }, 
   theaterId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "Theater" }, 
   seats: {}, 
});
```

Please help me with how to update the particular seat using the index value of the array as there is no unique id associated with it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried inserting one more key-value pair in my database collection of each array element called as "seatNo" which stores value as "A0", "A1", "A2".... where "A" is the "row" and "0" is the "col".

Then I tried this query: 
```
 collection.updateOne(
      {
        seats: {
          $elemMatch: {
            seatNo: { $eq: bookedTickets[i].row + bookedTickets[i].col },
          },
        },
      },
      { $set: { "seats.$.isAvailable": false } }
    );
```

Comment: I updated your question with above info.

Comment: The schema is a bit unclear. Do you use any unique id? What is `movieId` in this context?

Comment: @Christian Yes, its a unique mongoose ObjectID, so every movie has a unique ID and "seats" associated with it. To be very specific here is actual schema.

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  timing: { type: String, required: true },
  duration: { type: String, required: true },
  theaterId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "Theater" },
  seats: {},
});

Comment: you have error in your json, bookedSeats = [{row: "A", col: 0}, {row: "A", col" 1}, {row: "B", col: 2}], should be bookedSeats = [{row: "A", col: 0}, {row: "A", col: 1}, {row: "B", col: 2}]

Comment: @Nonik you can please ignore syntax error for now. Its just an example for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query which worked for me however I want to keep this thread open as my main query is about how to update mongodb data using the index value in my example.
Here is the query which worked out for me

```
let key = "seats." + bookedTickets[i].row + ".seatNo";
    let updationKey = "seats." + bookedTickets[i].row + ".$.isAvailable";
    
    try {
      await Movie.update(
        {
          _id: showId,
          [key]: bookedTickets[i].row + bookedTickets[i].col,
        },
        { $set: { [updationKey]: false } },
        (err, data) => {
          console.log(err, data);
          // return next(err);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of accomplishing this is to first find the document with `findOne`, calculate the new `seats` object based on the incoming bookings and finally save the document with the updated seat bookings:

```
const theaterToUpdate = await Theater.findOne({ theatherId: some_id } ).exec();
const seatsToBook = [{row: "A", col: 0}, {row: "A", col" 1}, {row: "B", col: 2}];
seatsToBook.forEach(seat => {
   theaterToUpdate.seats[seat.row][seat.col].isAvailable = false;
});
await theaterToUpdate.save();
```

Note that this will not be an atomic update but it might be ok depending on the requirements.

Comment: I have already tried this method, it doesnot work.

Comment: It it  not throwing any error. the returned data from the save() process looks updated but in mongodb collection it is not updated. However, I have manage to write a working query, but I still want this thread to be open as my main query is how to update using the index value.